# R Markdown output of bar plot different than output in the console

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to make an R Markdown document where a bar plot of urchin abundance and the associated analyses are printed.

I have written code to do this and running the code in the console results in the following figure which is what I want:

[image]

However, when I create a code chunk with this code and run it as an R Markdown with an html output, I get a figure that looks like this:

[image]

Note that the code for the first figure is in the R Markdown code chunk under the "# combined plot #" section

Also note that the beginning of this chunk is as follows: {r, results='hide', echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

#### Urchins R Markdown Code

```
### Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
library(MuMIn)
library(effects)
library(rcompanion)
library(png)


## Urchin Database

# database with starting urchins #
mean_urchin_totals2 <- structure(list(Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L
), Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1/30/18", "11/28/17", 
"12/3/17", "2/24/18", "3/10/18", "3/13/18", "3/23/18", "5/15/18", 
"5/20/18", "5/25/17", "6/6/17", "9/10/17", "9/5/17"), class = "factor"), 
    Reef.. = c(211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 
    113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
    211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
    115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 
    213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 116L, 113L, 114L, 111L, 112L, 115L, 
    211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
    115L, 116L), Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("HAN", "WAI"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CLO", "OPE"), class = "factor"), 
    TimeStep = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Site_long = c("Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki"
    ), Treatment_long = c("Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed"
    ), Shelter = c("High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
    "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low"), mean_urchin_abundance = c(25L, 
    2L, 3L, 6L, 44L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 47L, 15L, 47L, 7L, 67L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 30L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 48L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), 
    Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1/30/18", 
    "11/28/17", "12/3/17", "2/24/18", "3/10/18", "3/13/18", "3/23/18", 
    "5/15/18", "5/20/18", "5/25/17", "6/6/17", "9/10/17", "9/5/17"
    ), class = "factor"), Reef.. = c(211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
    215L, 216L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 111L, 112L, 
    113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
    215L, 216L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 116L, 113L, 
    114L, 111L, 112L, 115L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L), Site = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("HAN", 
    "WAI"), class = "factor"), Treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CLO", 
    "OPE"), class = "factor"), TimeStep = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Site_long = c("Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", "Hanauma Bay", 
    "Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", "Waikiki", 
    "Waikiki", "Waikiki"), Treatment_long = c("Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Open", "Closed", "Open", 
    "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", "Open", "Closed", 
    "Open", "Closed"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
        8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
        19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
        30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
        41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
        52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

mean_urchin_totals2$new_date <- strptime(as.character(mean_urchin_totals2$Date), "%m/%d/%y")
mean_urchin_totals2$new_date <- as.Date(mean_urchin_totals2$new_date)
mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter <- ifelse(mean_urchin_totals2$Treatment_long == "Closed", "Low", "High")
mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter <- factor(mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"))
mean_urchin_totals2$Site_long <- as.factor(mean_urchin_totals2$Site_long)
mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter <- as.factor(mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter)
mean_urchin_totals2$Year <- as.factor(mean_urchin_totals2$Year)


## Urchin Analyses
### Distribution
# variables
module_urchin2 <- mean_urchin_totals2$Reef..

plotNormalHistogram(mean_urchin_totals2$mean_urchin_abundance, main = "Urchins")


### glmer with Poisson Distribution
mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter <- factor(mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter, levels = c("High", "Low"))
mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter <- sort(mean_urchin_totals2$Shelter, decreasing = FALSE)

# with EUME, ECMA #
urchin_glmer <- glmer(mean_urchin_abundance ~ Site_long + Shelter + Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_urchin2), data = mean_urchin_totals2, family = poisson, na.action = "na.fail")
summary(urchin_glmer)

# Effects plots #
plot(allEffects(urchin_glmer))

# Residuals glmer #
qqnorm(resid(urchin_glmer), main = "Urchin Residual Plot")
qqline(resid(urchin_glmer))

# Pairwise multiple comparisons #
emm_urchin <- emmeans(urchin_glmer, ~Site_long*Shelter)
pairs(emm_urchin, simple = "each")


### Best Model
# Best model #
dredge(urchin_glmer, extra = "R^2")

urchin_glmer_1 <- glmer(mean_urchin_abundance ~ Site_long + Shelter + Year + (1|module_urchin2), data = mean_urchin_totals2, family = poisson, na.action = "na.fail")
summary(urchin_glmer_1)

# Effects plots #
plot(allEffects(urchin_glmer_1))

# Residuals glmer #
qqnorm(resid(urchin_glmer_1), main = "Urchin Residual Plot")
qqline(resid(urchin_glmer_1))

# emmeans package #
emm <- emmeans(urchin_glmer_1, ~ Site_long*Shelter)
pairs(emm)


## Urchin Plots
### Summary Database
#barplot CI
std.dev.pop <- function(x) sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x)))
std.error.pop <- function(x) (std.dev.pop(x))/(sqrt(length(x)))

plot_data_Site4 <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>%
  group_by(Site_long, Treatment_long, Shelter) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mean_urchin_abundance),
            sd = std.dev.pop(mean_urchin_abundance),
            lower = mean(mean_urchin_abundance) - 1.96*std.error.pop(mean_urchin_abundance),
            upper = mean(mean_urchin_abundance) + 1.96*std.error.pop(mean_urchin_abundance))

# reorder summary dataframe for plotting #
plot_data_Site4 <- plot_data_Site4[c(3,4,1,2),]
plot_data_Site4$Shelter <- factor(plot_data_Site4$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"))
plot_data_Site4$Site_long <- factor(plot_data_Site4$Site_long, levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"))

# ggplot2 barplot final #
position <- c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay")


### Plots
# plot #
urchin_plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data_Site4, aes(fill=Shelter, y=mean, x=Site_long)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", width = .8) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = position) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, 5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(.8), width = .1) +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Shelter", start = .8, end = .2) +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± 95% CI") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.1, .9))


# plot without legend #
urchin_plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data_Site4, aes(fill=Shelter, y=mean, x=Site_long)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", width = .8) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = position) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, 5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(.8), width = .1) +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Shelter", start = .8, end = .2) +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± 95% CI") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")


# combined plot #
mult_compare4 <- c( "A", "A","B", "C")

urchin_plot_final <- ggplot(data = plot_data_Site4, aes(fill=Shelter, y=mean, x=Site_long)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", width = .8) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = position) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30, 5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(.8), width = .1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = mult_compare4, y = plot_data_Site4$upper + 0.05), vjust = -.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  scale_fill_grey(name = "Shelter", start = .8, end = .2) +
  labs(x = "Site", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± 95% CI") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 13) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))

urchin_plot_final


## Urchin Time Series Plots
### Summary Databases
## Time Series Plots ###
## Subsetting for time series figures ##
HAN_OPE_urchin <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>% filter(Site_long == "Hanauma Bay", Treatment_long == "Open")
HAN_CLO_urchin <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>% filter(Site_long == "Hanauma Bay", Treatment_long == "Closed")
WAI_OPE_urchin <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>% filter(Site_long == "Waikiki", Treatment_long == "Open")
WAI_CLO_urchin <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>% filter(Site_long == "Waikiki", Treatment_long == "Closed")


### Population SE ###
std.dev.pop <- function(x) sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x)))
std.error.pop <- function(x) (std.dev.pop(x))/(sqrt(length(x)))

plot_data_urchin <- mean_urchin_totals2 %>%
  group_by(TimeStep, Shelter, Treatment_long, Site_long) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mean_urchin_abundance),
            sd = std.dev.pop(mean_urchin_abundance),
            lower = mean(mean_urchin_abundance) - std.error.pop(mean_urchin_abundance),
            upper = mean(mean_urchin_abundance) + std.error.pop(mean_urchin_abundance),
            Date = mean(new_date))

# add shelter column #
plot_data_urchin$Shelter <- ifelse(plot_data_urchin$Treatment_long == "Closed", "Low", "High")
plot_data_urchin$Shelter <- factor(plot_data_urchin$Shelter, levels = c("Low", "High"))


### Time Series Plots
## full plot ##
urchin_time_series_plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data_urchin, aes(x = Date, y = mean, group = interaction(Site_long, Treatment_long))) + geom_line(aes(linetype = Treatment_long)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Site_long, size = 3, color = Treatment_long)) +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b%y") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, .5)) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± SEM")

## cropped plot ##
urchin_time_series_plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data_urchin, aes(x = Date, y = mean, fill = Shelter, shape = Site_long)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 3)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Shelter)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "black"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 20, 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 18)) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± SEM") +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), legend.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)))

## cropped plot for combined figure ##
legend_image <- readPNG('Legend_final2.png')
xmin <- as.Date("2018/01/01")
xmax <- as.Date("2018/03/21")
ymin <- 40
ymax <- 51

urchin_time_series_plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data_urchin, aes(x = Date, y = mean, fill = Shelter, shape = Site_long)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = 3)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Shelter)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "solid")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "black"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) +
  guides(size = FALSE) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 55, 10)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 55)) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Mean urchin abundance ± SEM") +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1)), axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)), legend.text = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90), legend.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5)), legend.position = "none") 

urchin_time_series_plot
```

I am looking to make an output where the html created has the urchin figure the same as the first figure from above.  Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: heck1 my mistake that was an oversight on my part.  I used dput and created an object "mean_urchin_totals2" that contains data for a reproducible example.  Please let me know if there is any other confusion.  Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, what is the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem? I'm not asking because I'm lazy (well, maybe a bit), but figuring that out sometimes exposes where it goes wrong. Are chunk options wrong, or are parts of the analyses cached?

Comment: teunbrand the minimum amount of code needed is the "mean_urchin_totals2" object containing data, the processing of the database that immediately follows, and the "Urchin Plots" section.  The analysis and time series sections aren't necessary but I wanted to include everything that is in the chunk in case some obscure part of my code is causing the issue.  To answer your last question, the lead in to my r chunk is as follows: {r, results='hide', echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}